# Azure Function Create Word Document

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

(.NetCore/C#)
I am trying to create an Azure Function that will be triggered when changes are made in CosmosDB. The goal of the function is to generate a report word document file based on data from CosmosDB. The current way I am approaching this task is to use DocX library to generate the word file. I managed to create a test file that can create a local file and upload it to Azure storage. However, when I tried to apply it to my main Azure Function code I realized that I do not have a place to store the word document file that I want to generate and upload to Azure Storage. Is there a way around this issue?

```html
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string Directory = @"C:\Project";
    string Filename = @"\report.docx";
    string FilenamePath = Directory + Filename;

    var Doc = DocX.Create(FilenamePath);

    Formatting Format = new Formatting();
    Format.FontFamily = new Font("Gotham Office");  
    Format.Size = 18;
    Format.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    Format.Bold = true;

    string Text = "Text";
    Doc.InsertParagraph(Text, false, Format);

    Doc.Save();
    try
    {
        Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", FilenamePath);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception e)
    {
    }
    SaveToBlob(FilenamePath);
}
public static void SaveToBlob(string FilenamePath)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Connection String");
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("report");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("report.docx");
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FilenamePath))
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Another concern I have for this current approach is that it is using WINWORD.EXE, which I am afraid might not work with the Azure Function Environment. Are there any better libraries that I should use for the task?

Comment: I have tried with this approach, but it always says File cannot be found.
string FilenamePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "report.docx");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test with `DocX` package I could reproduce this problem, looks like this package is for net framework, could not work with .net core. If you are using a different environment please let me know.

So then I change the package to `DocX_Doc` and below is my test code, bind the blob container output, create a doc file, and upload it.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Novacode;

namespace FunctionApp46
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Blob("out",FileAccess.ReadWrite,Connection ="AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudBlobContainer container,
            ExecutionContext context, 
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var path = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "a.doc");
            FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
            fs.Close();

            var Doc = DocX.Create(path);
            Formatting Format = new Formatting();
            Format.FontFamily = new Font("Gotham Office");
            Format.Size = 18;
            Format.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            Format.Bold = true;

            Doc.InsertParagraph("test");
            Doc.Save();
            var blockblob=container.GetBlockBlobReference("a.doc");
            await blockblob.UploadFromFileAsync(path);

            return new OkObjectResult("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

It will create a doc file under the wwwroot folder. Maybe you could have a try, hope this could help you , if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have tried using this method before, unfortunately for some reason I always received an error File not found using this method. I managed to find a similar solution using "d:/local" directory. Which as I understand is the local directory that the Azure code is running on.

Comment: For the upload to blob part, I am currently using the UploadFromStreamAsync() method. Is there any difference between UploadFromStreamAsync() and UploadFromFileAsync() ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for this issue. I used "d:\local" to hold the created file path.